# Problem when building network with spatialite-gui

Tags: network, shortest-path, spatialite-gui

I would like to find the shortest path between two points in the following graph and corresponding table:

[image]

[image]

I am using spatialite-gui for windows version 1.2.1 and I am having a problem when building the network.
It works fine when I build it with the following parameters :

[image]

(“OK: VirtualNetwork table ‘road_net’ successfully created”)

I can then run the SQL query and get the correct result (assuming all roads are bi-directionnal).

But when I’m trying to build the network with one-way directions (parameters bellow), I get: “It’s impossible to build a Network using the given configuration; some fatal error occurred”

[image]

I don’t understand why this won’t work. ‘oneway_fromto’ and ‘oneway_tofrom’ are filled with booleans.

Comment: Perhaps because you have edges like A-C which are oneway for both directions. Test by editing all 1-1 cases into 1-0.

Comment: @user30184 Just tried it, it doesn't work either. Thank's for the help anyway

Comment: I have used oneway columns with OpenStreetMap data so I know it is possible.

Comment: @user30184 Ok, so maybe it comes from the way I create or populate my table. In Python:
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE road ('id' INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 'name' VARCHAR(255), 'fromnode' VARCHAR(255), 'tonode' VARCHAR(255), 'oneway_fromto' BOOLEAN , 'oneway_tofrom' BOOLEAN)")
cur.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('road', 'geometry', 4326, 'LINESTRING', 'XY')")

cur.execute("""INSERT INTO road VALUES(NULL, 'A-C', 'A', 'C', 1, 0, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 13, 11 1)',4326))""")
conn.commit()

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: Spatialite tools seem to do it a bit differently: `CREATE TABLE "way" (
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
osm_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
class TEXT NOT NULL,
node_from INTEGER NOT NULL,
node_to INTEGER NOT NULL,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
oneway_fromto INTEGER NOT NULL,
oneway_tofrom INTEGER NOT NULL,
length DOUBLE NOT NULL,
cost DOUBLE NOT NULL, "geometry" LINESTRING)`. However, for SQLite the datatypes does not have so big meaning. For oneways "1" seems to mean that travel is allowed and 1-1 case is OK and means that way is not oneway.

Comment: @user30184 I still get the same error. I don't see where else the problem could come from. I guess not from the SRID since it works with bi-directionnal edges.

Comment: Does it fail even if you update all the values in oneway_fromto and oneway_tofrom into "1"?

Comment: @user30184 Yes, still the same error

Comment: Could you share your spatialite database?

Comment: @user30184 Don't know if this works: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g5y22xfwrda5z9l/db.sqlite?dl=0

Comment: Works for me with spatialite-gui 1.8.0. The Spatialite site is messy but try for example with this version http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86.

Comment: @user30184 Works perfectly, thank you! So it was just a problem of spatialite-gui versions?

Answer (score 1):

There must have been a bug in spatialite-gui for windows version 1.2.1. For example spatialite-gui version 1.8.0 creates virtual network table from your data and with the same selections just fine.

[image]

[image]